# Create a zip with only .pdf and .xml files from one directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, os.walk, python-zipfile

I would love to know how i can zip only all pdfs from the main directory without including the subfolders.

I've tried several times changing the code, without any succes with what i want to achieve.

```
import zipfile
 
fantasy_zip = zipfile.ZipFile('/home/rob/Desktop/projects/zenjobv2/archivetest.zip', 'w')
 
for folder, subfolders, files in os.walk('/home/rob/Desktop/projects/zenjobv2/'):
 
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.pdf'):
            fantasy_zip.write(os.path.join(folder, file), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder,file), '/home/rob/Desktop/projects/zenjobv2/'), compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
        elif file.endswith('.xml'):
            fantasy_zip.write(os.path.join(folder, file), os.path.relpath(os.path.join(folder,file), '/home/rob/Desktop/projects/zenjobv2/'), compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
fantasy_zip.close()
```

I expect that a zip is created only with the .pdfs and .xml files from the zenjobv2 folder/directory without including any other folders/subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through the entire directory tree with [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).  It sounds like you want to just look at the files in a given directory.  For that, consider [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir), which returns an iterator of all files and subdirectories in a given directory.  You will just have to filter out elements that are directories:

```
root = "/home/rob/Desktop/projects/zenjobv2"
for entry in os.scandir(root):
    if entry.is_dir():
        continue  # Just in case there are strangely-named directories
    if entry.path.endswith(".pdf") or entry.path.endswith(".xml"):
        # Process the file at entry.path as you see fit
```

Comment: thanks, i will check that out. Do you have an idea  how to only look for .pdf and .xml in the main directory WITHOUT looking in subdir1 and subdir2 for the .pdf/.xml files. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are looping through subdirectories with `os.walk()`, which will step through the entire directory tree.  Consider [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) instead.